# Excel vba, retrieve contact info from Outlook, cannot retrive location column

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I can't get the location part of the contacts list, it just shows up blank.

[image]

```
Sub GetOutlookAddressBook()
    Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application, objAddressList As Outlook.AddressList
    Dim oItem As Outlook.AddressEntry, i As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set objAddressList = objOutlook.Session.AddressLists("Global Address List")
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A:C").ClearContents
    i = 2
    For Each oItem In objAddressList.AddressEntries

        If oItem.Address <> "" Then
          Cells(i, "A") = oItem.Name
          Cells(i, "B") = oItem.GetExchangeUser.ALIAS
          Cells(i, "C") = oItem.GetExchangeUser.PrimarySmtpAddress
          Cells(i, "D") = oItem.GetExchangeUser.Department
          Cells(i, "E") = oItem.GetExchangeUser.Location 'cannot get location

            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Location` is not a Property of the `ExchangeUser` object.  You may be after either the `Address` or `OfficeLocation` properties

Here is a list of properties, taken from [the Object Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.exchangeuser#properties) in the Microsoft Documentation

```
Address
AddressEntryUserType
Alias
Application
AssistantName
BusinessTelephoneNumber
City
Class
Comments
CompanyName
Department
DisplayType
FirstName
ID
JobTitle
LastName
MobileTelephoneNumber
Name
OfficeLocation
Parent
PostalCode
PrimarySmtpAddress
PropertyAccessor
Session
StateOrProvince
StreetAddress
Type
YomiCompanyName
YomiDepartment
YomiDisplayName
YomiFirstName
YomiLastName
```

Comment: Thanks, turns out to be City